# Delete an Item from Array not Rendering ReactJS Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to delete an item from Array using the Index, 
I am Passing the Props from Parent to Child Component to perform this operation, now i can see the console log that it's getting deleted, but it's not rendering the component

I have Posted the code in SandBox, since it will get messy here

Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-burnell-qkl7r

Comment: please add code here, instead of linking to it.

Comment: I would if I can.. It has 2 files.. It will be messy

Comment: Yes, but the problem is in deleteHandler function.

Comment: Refer this guide, https://vegibit.com/how-to-delete-an-item-from-an-array-in-react/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are rendering data from `props.listofapi` but updating array, your changes don't get updated because you are changing the wrong array. [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) removes/adds an item to/from array, you don't have to do `setArray(...array, temp);` but `setArray(tempArray);`

use useEffect to save the initial data to array.

```
const deleteHandler = id => {
  console.log(id);
  const tempArray = [...array];
  // removes item from tempArray
  tempArray.splice(id, 1); 
  setArray(tempArray);
  console.log("temp array", tempArray);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  // data from props to array here
  setArray(props.listofapi);
}, [props.listofapi]);
```

and map array instead of `props.listofapi`

```
<TableBody>
      {array.map((row, index) => (
      ...
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-river-epemm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Hey man, I guess you forgot to add `props.listofapi` as a `Effect` dependencies. it doesn't work without.

Answer (score 1):

The component only re-renders if there are `state` changes, what you actually doing is passing the `props` from `parent` to `child`, which are not `state` values.
Hence you can try this following way where we need to set the local state first, so that when the state gets updated , the component will be re-renderd.

Just update the code with the following things

```
  React.useEffect(() =>{
    setArray(props.listofapi)
    //this acts as componentdidmount

  },[]);

  React.useEffect(() =>{
    console.log('state value changed', array)
    // this is the way a call back function is called in the hooks
  },[array]);
```

I have update the [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-mestorf-f8377)

Answer (score 1):

in your RenderList component, you need to set the state as the props that are being passed

```
const RenderList = props => {
  // console.log(props.listofapi);
  const classes = useStyles();


  const [array, setArray] = React.useState(props.listofapi); // to update the component

  const deleteHandler = index=> {
    console.log(id);
    setArray(array.filter((item, i) => i!== index));
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer
      component={Paper}
      className={classes.table}
      style={{ align: "center" }}
    >
      <Table
        stickyHeader
        className={classes.container}
        size="small"
        aria-label="a dense table"
      >
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>User ID</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Use Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Email ID</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Edit </TableCell>
            <TableCell>Delete</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {array.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.id}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.username}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.email}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button variant="contained" size="small" color="primary">
                  Edit Me
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  size="small"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={() => deleteHandler(index)}
                >
                  Delete Me
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};
export default RenderList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem you just misused spared. Try this:

```js
  const deleteHandler = id => {
    // do your logic on the array that coming from props
    let temp = props.listofapi.splice(id, 1);
    // using spread
    setArray([...array, temp]);
  };
```

See your Code at [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-cdn-8yil4)

**Edit:** Please note that you are editing/deleting and mapping directly over the `props.listofapi` array and so, the `.splice()` method will change/remove its existing elements. If you don't want that, you should try **@Junius L.** solution.

Comment: Actually no, not necessarily. You still can edit the array that passed from props (see my sandbox link) but its not recommend unless you need to.